# Firebase Database: Unknown node type with seperated firebase initilization logic

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

Minimal Repo: https://github.com/ljrahn/firebase-unknown-node-type

When firebase initialization logic is seperated into a seperate package, and imported, an error occurs with realtime database listeners. This issue as far as i know only occurs with the realtime database listeners ie. onChildAdded, onValue, and doesnt occur with eg. get, or any other service, eg. firestore. Additionally, it only occurs when seperated, built, and imported. If i define the initilization logic directly in the nextjs app, it works as expected. Furthermore, this only occurs when I have 2 conditions on the query, eg. limitToFirst(5) AND orderByChild("updatedAt"), if only one is present, the error is not triggered (although there is another weird issue if only limitToFirst is set, then onChildRemoved is triggered immediately after onChildAdded, even though it shouldnt be, but regardless, this is less important).

Note I have been using this strategy of building the initilization logic in a seperate package and importing it for a while. This only started occuring when I try to do what is described: toggle a realtime database listener with two QueryConstraint's

Initilization Logic:

```
declare global {
  var EMULATORS_STARTED: boolean;
}
const EMULATORS_STARTED = "EMULATORS_STARTED";
let app: FirebaseApp, rtdb: Database;

const connectEmulator = () => {
  if (!global[EMULATORS_STARTED]) {
    global[EMULATORS_STARTED] = true;

    connectDatabaseEmulator(rtdb, "127.0.0.1", 9000);
  }
};

export const initializeFirebase = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    projectId: "demo-project-id",
    databaseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=demo-project-id-default-rtdb",
  };

  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  rtdb = getDatabase(app);

  connectEmulator();

  return { app, rtdb };
};
```

When I try to import the initilization and set the listener:

```
import { initializeFirebase } from "../../deps/build/firebase";

  const { rtdb } = initializeFirebase();

  const conversationsQuery = query(
    ref(rtdb, "data"),
    limitToFirst(5),
    orderByChild("updatedAt")
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const onChildAddedUnsubscribe = onChildAdded(conversationsQuery, (data) => {
      console.log("added");
    });

    return () => {
      onChildAddedUnsubscribe();
    };

}, [])
```

I get the following error if data is in the database: `Error: Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Unknown node type`

If I import NOT from the build, eg. `import { initializeFirebase } from "../../deps/firebase"`, it works exactly as expected.

This is a reproduced example. My actual app requires that the firebase logic is seperated into a seperate package, because I use the package as an API for multiple other clients (eg. a cli). I would much rather not just duplicate the initialization logic into my nextjs app, and there would also be other side effects.

Comment: If you use an expected `databaseURL` format, does the problem go away? `"https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com"` (e.g. `"https://demo-project-id.firebaseio.com"`)

Comment: @samthecodingman no unfortunately not :( just tried changing and it didnt work. That's also how i had it set in my original project, and same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the source for the `firebase-js-sdk`, the lines causing you grief are [located here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/9fa0e9f5f2b29b09c72b66c69d4d99b3f97e0830/packages/database/src/core/snap/LeafNode.ts#L212-L221):

```js
compareTo(other: Node): number {
  if (other === LeafNode.__childrenNodeConstructor.EMPTY_NODE) {
    return 1;
  } else if (other instanceof LeafNode.__childrenNodeConstructor) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    assert(other.isLeafNode(), 'Unknown node type');
    return this.compareToLeafNode_(other as LeafNode);
  }
}
```

Because some of your code is pre-built, there is no way for the nodes from the pre-built code to ever equal the sentinel value of `LeafNode.__childrenNodeConstructor.EMPTY_NODE` or be instances of `LeafNode.__childrenNodeConstructor`. This means that the logic will incorrectly hit the `other.isLeafNode()` check which returns `false` and throws the assertion error. Under normal operation, one of the other two branches would have returned a different value.

As you've identified, this means you will need to make sure that all of your Firebase code is built at the same time. You can't build off a partially built Firebase SDK.

---

One potential workaround would be to move all your query logic into your pre-built code and expose the methods needed to invoke the queries, passing in callbacks that are called with plain JavaScript objects containing the requested data.

As a crude (don't use this as-is) example:

```
// in firebase file (before build time)

export const initializeFirebase = () => { ... };

const { rtdb } = initializeFirebase();

export const onTopConversationChildAdded = (callback) => {

  const conversationsQuery = query(
    ref(rtdb, "data"),
    limitToFirst(5),
    orderByChild("updatedAt")
  );
  
  return childAdded(ref, snap => callback(snap.data()));
}
```

```
// in component file
import { onTopConversationChildAdded } from "../../deps/build/firebase";

useEffect(() => {
  return onTopConversationChildAdded((data) => console.log('added'));
});
```

---

You could might also be able to just export whatever you need from your pre-built code (e.g. `ref`, `limitToFirst`, etc).

Comment: Yes your suggestion is definitely the move. Thanks Sam!